# dynamic user list consumer in Django channels

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, django, sockets, django-channels

I'm using Django(3.2.11) with the Postgres database. I'm creating a chat app with Django channels. so I created a message consumer and save it into the database. and also created a message history consumer by room. now I want to create a user list consumer which has dynamic messages with the user name. for that I made a consumer who returns infinite data.
like:-

```
class ChatListConsumer(AsyncJsonWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        self.room_group_name = 'chat_list_%s' % self.scope['user'].user_id
        self.connection = True
        await self.channel_layer.group_add(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )
        await self.accept()

    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        self.connection = False
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

    def get_serializer(self, obj):
        return {'data': ProductQueryUsersSerializer(
            instance=obj.order_by('-updated_at'), many=True
        ).data, 'type': "chat_list"}

    async def receive(self, text_data):
        while self.connection:
            try:
                self.query = await database_sync_to_async(
                    ProductQueryUsers.objects.filter
                )(Q(seller__user=self.scope['user']) | Q(user=self.scope['user'])
                  )
                data = await database_sync_to_async(self.get_serializer)(self.query)
            except EmptyPage:
                data = {'data': [], 'type': "chat_list"}
            await self.send(text_data=json.dumps(data))
```

and call this in javascript like:-

```
<div id="message"></div>
    <script>
        const chatSocket = new WebSocket('ws://192.168.29.72:8000/ws/chat-list/?user=VXNlcjo4Mg==');
        chatSocket.onopen = function(e){
            chatSocket.send(JSON.stringify({}));
            console.log("open", e);
        };
        chatSocket.onmessage = function(e) {
            const data = JSON.parse(e.data);
            console.log(data)
            data.data.forEach(function (item, index, arr) {
                var element = document.getElementById(item.room_id);
                if (typeof(element) != 'undefined' && element != null){
                    document.getElementById(item.room_id).innerHTML = item.last_message.message
                } else {
                     document.getElementById('message').innerHTML += `<h1 id="${item.room_id}">${item.last_message.message}</h1>`
                }
            });
        };
        chatSocket.onerror = function(e){
            console.log("error", e)
        };
        chatSocket.onclose = function(e){
            console.log("close", e)
        };

    </script>
```

it infinite time return users' list with their last message. but when it run another socket does not connect. so how can I create a user list consumer with the last message received? and call the three sockets on the same page.